# Adding an EditText to jfeinstein sliding menu

Tags: android, android-edittext, slidingmenu

I am working on an android project and I am making use of jfeinstein sliding menu library, library can be located at https://github.com/jfeinstein10/slidingmenu.

I have got the library working fine and have amended my code to make it work with other components, not just TextViews, such as Switches. I am now trying to add an EditText to the menu so that the user can enter directly in the box without having to switch activities.

I have it so I have a called `MenuAdapter` which extends `ArrayAdapter`. This then has a series of constructors which, based on the constructor and what values are passed into, determine which control is added to the sliding menu. The `EditText` is being added to the sliding menu and the hint is being sent, and when I tap on the edit text the keyboard is displayed but if I type anything, its not shown in the EditText. However, oddly, if I long press on the edit text and click paste, I can view the content that is pasted so its just typing that's not working.

Below is the XML layout, each component is hidden using the visibility set to `gone` and then is set to be displayed dependent on the constructor that was used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_icon"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <Switch 
        android:id="@+id/row_switch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/White"/>

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/row_edittext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the code for how the `EditText` is being addd to the menu.

```
case EDITEXT:
    EditText editText = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(getItem(position).viewID);
    editText.setHint(getItem(position).hint);
        editText.setEnabled(true);
    editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.